# htaccess GET not working properly with keyword store

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having a problem with the keyword "store" when it is passed into the URL and my .htaccess GETs it. Any other page just shows whatever.com/page but when I use the page "store" it shows whatever.com/store?id=store instead of just whatever.com/store

This is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

This is my nav. Everything works properly except the "store". I can name it to "stores" and it will work perfectly. Does this have anything to do with "store" being an htaccess keyword or something?

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>
        <a href="about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="store">Store</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <?php 
   if ($_SESSION['logged_in']) {
        echo "<li><a href='pages/logout'>Logout</a></li>";
   }
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing it to sth. else, perhaps "shop" ?

Comment: is store a real directory? Also in your 2nd rule you should change this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l` to this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

Comment: Yes store is a real directory. If I simply change the href in my `nav` from `store` to `shop` or to `storee` without changing anything else, it will pull up the correct page.